# Is it possible to download and install multiple versions of Safari on macOS?

Tags: macos, safari, versions

Is it possible to download and install multiple versions of Safari on macOS?
I need to test something out on my MacBook with the latest version of Safari (13), but I don't want to update my current Safari browser to the latest version. I want to be able to keep my current older version of Safari **UNTOUCHED** and the newest version of Safari both installed and usable on my Mac computer. Is this possible?

Comment: Not very easily. Virtual machine seems to be a way. I don't know if you can keep multiple partitions for multiple os versions.

Comment: someone else told me I would just need to rename my old version as Legacy Safari or something like that and that I should still be able to run both

Comment: is virtual box the best free VM?

Comment: I have no idea how to use a VM, can you help me out?

Comment: you can try Parallels with its 15 days trial. If it works well, VirtualBox is free, just looks weird. I haven't tried vmware

Comment: I downloaded and installed VirtualBox. But I don't know how to use it. All I want to do is run macOS High Sierra in VirtualBox on my MacBook laptop that is also running High Sierra.

Comment: You could just use something like [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/) to run any version of Safari you need.

Comment: Ok thank you Nic, I will try out BrowserStack as well.

Answer (score 2):

Updates to Safari tend to include updates to the WebKit system framework on which Safari relies. (The WebKit framework is separate from the app, and is then available to other apps.)

Executing an app that was built for a different framework from the last one you installed is likely to cause problems.

Comment: Someone on another site told me I should use Safari Technology Preview app. Is that a good idea?

Comment: Safari Preview is like a beta. It's an advance look at new technologies. It will have benefits and disadvantages.

Comment: Can I use Safari Preview for an older version of Safari such as Safari version 11.12?

Comment: Do you have an external hard drive? you might download latest version of Safari onto an external hard drive.

Comment: No, I do not. At least no drive that is empty. All the drives I have have data on them.

Comment: I want to test out and use two different versions of Safari, Safari 11.1.2 and Safari 13. Just to make sure, it isn't my specific installation of Safari 11.1.2 that is the problem. Also I would want to test out Safari 13 to make sure it's not my computer that is causing the issue I am facing.

Comment: Can you describe the broader 'issue' you're having in more detail? Perhaps there's another way to solve it.

Comment: @benwiggy I can not post comments on Youtube with my current version of Safari 11.1.2. Also, I can not view my notifications in the bell icon in Youtube. I first experienced these two issues at exactly the same time. Roughly 5 or 6 days ago. I assume they are the result of the same problem.

Comment: @Arlen: did this happen immediately after you updated the OS or Safari? Because there might be another cause if not. Sounds like you don't need to test multiple version of Safari, but rather just find a version that works with YouTube. Why don't you want to update Safari to a newer version?

Comment: No, I didn't update anything. I don't even think I installed anything.

Comment: @Arlen Well, if everything was working before, with the same version of Safari, then you shouldn't need to change the version of Safari to get it working again!  Your problem may be caused by some settings or some other piece of software interfering. Perhaps ask another question, describing exactly what happens when you try to post comments on YouTube.

Comment: Trying to install Safari 14.0 on macOS 10.15.7 (replacing 14.1) failed so I tried to install it to the desktop.  That also failed so I tried to delete the stuff off the desktop.  That hung and I couldn't log in until I reinstalled macOS.  Are the tech preview installers less tied up with the rest of the OS?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is probably not possible because Safari is a part of macOS. New versions of Safari come with macOS but you can try finding the Safari downloads at https://support.apple.com/downloads. Double click the .dmg file and complete the installation.

Comment: Someone on another site told me I should use Safari Technology Preview app. Is that a good idea?

Comment: I've never heard of it but I wouldn't recommend it if it is third party. If you really do need different versions, you can try using a macOS Virtual Machine. If you want a macOS VM, you will need the ISO.

Comment: It's this: https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/

Comment: Seems legit, you should try it.

Comment: The only problem is it's only for the current version of Safari 13, not Safari 11. And if there are previews for Safari 11.1.2, I don't know where to find them.

Comment: I don't know either. Again, you should see if you can find the version you are looking for at https://support.apple.com/downloads

Comment: Ok, but I don't have a empty drive to download and install one of those versions.

Comment: You don't need one. It will install a .dmg which is a regular disk image.

Comment: So it won't update or break my current installation of Safari 11.1.2 that I am using?

Comment: It shouldn't. It hasn't done that for me. I just tried it on my Mac. If it does, then you can reinstall Safari from the Apple Support website. If you are hesitant, try a macOS Virtual Machine first.

Comment: Can I install a version of Safari on a micro SD card?

Comment: What version of Safari did you just install?

Comment: I tried Safari 5

Comment: Can that be updated to Safari 11.1.2 so I can test that specific version?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try downloading 11.1.2 directly if its there,

Comment: It's not there, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I can't tell if it can be updated because my Mac just stopped working. You can try doing it.

Comment: Older Technology Previews are still downloadable by archive.org.