# Can someone please help me set up a Virtual Machine of macOS High Sierra using VirtualBox?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, virtualbox

I want to create a Virtual Machine of macOS High Sierra using VirtualBox 6.1 on my  mid 2014 MacBook Pro that's running macOS.

How do I do that?

I already installed VirtualBox.

How do I create the VM of macOS High Sierra now?

Comment: @david https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/386749/is-it-possible-to-download-and-install-multiple-versions-of-safari-on-macos#comment527914_386749

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install macOS Sierra on VirtualBox?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290643/install-macos-sierra-on-virtualbox)

Comment: @DavidAnderson It's mid 2014. yes it can, but I want to use VirtualBox because I have never used I it before and just want to play around with it. I have VirtualBox 6.1, should be the latest version.

Comment: @DavidAnderson ok

Comment: @DavidAnderson Isn't that against the rules? That's considered cross-posting isn't? To post the same post on two different StackExhcange sites.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I am going to move this conversation to a chat. Will the chat get deleted if I delete the post?

Comment: @Nic That seems like it might answer my question. Thank you for the comment. I am now going to move this conversation to a chat if you would like to continue this conversation we can do it there.

Comment: @Arien: When you posted your question on Super User, I immediately posted an short answer, then deleted the answer.  This permits me to edit and complete my answer before undeleting the answer. As it turns out, the question was closed, but since I first posted before the closing and now have undeleted, my answer is viewable by you. I also posted my answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290643/install-macos-sierra-on-virtualbox/387286#387286) at Ask Different, where everyone can see it.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Ok good to know. Thank you. I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Arlen: In chat, you indicated irritation and frustration. I will omit the system has flaws, but still Ask Different has helped many with their Mac problems. I can assure you that the users in charge really what to see you get an answer to your question.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Oh yeah, it kind of was. Yes, I know they have, and I appreciate all the help. I think it's that I was trying to get an answer for multiple days and making multiple posts on multiple different sites, while talking to multiple people with somewhat different answers that made me feel that way. Also, probably because I was admittedly a little inpatient. But I appreciate the help nonetheless. Also, I haven't been able to test out Virtualbox with the method you described, as well as the method Nic linked above, but I'm sure they will probably work. Hopefully.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I can't currently comment on the answer you posted in that link above because I don't have 50 reputation points, I only have 49, but I had a question I wanted to ask. Do I have to use a USB flash drive to make a macOS virtual machine on VirtualBox? I currently do not have a USB flash drive, though I could potentially borrow one from a friend nearby.

Comment: @Arlen: You have 59 reputation points. You do not have to use a flash drive. I will have to update my answer. I will post a comment when I have done so.

Comment: I added a [new answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290643/install-macos-sierra-on-virtualbox/387404#387404).